# How to paste the website link into excel which is linked to the website?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q0S2.png)

[image]
Hi all,

I want to paste a website link into excel so that once I click the link, it will direct me to the website. However, some of the cells in my excel worksheet work well but some are not as shown in the screenshot above. May I know is there any thing that I need to adjust in term of format? Thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe specify which version of Excel you're using? This post implies that it is may behave differently depending on the version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/77921/excel-2013-now-autoformats-urls-as-hyperlinks-when.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter what appears to be a web address Excel will automatically convert it into a hyperlink. It will then appear in blue and underscored. To get rid of the hyperlink select the cell and type "Remove hyperlink" in the *Help* field.

After that the web address becomes normal text and appears black. You can simply invoke the first mentioned automation by clicking in the cell, press F2 and Enter.

Comment: when I paste a link on the cell, it automatically turn the link to a text instead of hyperlink. Is there any method to set the cell read the web link as hyperlink instead of a text?

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Excel (Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13426.20270)), a pasted text is turned into a hyperlink if it is pasted in "write" or "edit" mode for a cell and then "Enter" or "Tab" is pressed.

"Write" mode can be invoked by double-clicking on a cell. "Edit" mode can be invoked by for example pressing F2, or clicking on the *formula bar* which is normally displayed as a text-field above the cell matrix.